# The web scraping issue in python, web page not loading in time

Tags: python-3.x, exception, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making a program for scrapping the Amazon websites mobile phones but my program is giving me timeout exception even after the page is loaded on time.
Here is my code

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request

    class Amazon_all_mobile_scraper:
        def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.delay = 60
            self.url = "https://www.amazon.in/mobile-phones/b/ref=sd_allcat_sbc_mobcomp_all_mobiles?ie=UTF8&node=1389401031"

        def load_amazon(self):
            self.driver.get(self.url)
            try:
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,self.delay)
                        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"acs-ln-link")))
                print("Page is ready.")
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Took too much time to load!")
            except:
                print("Something went wrong in loading part!!")

        def extract_list_of_mobiles(self):
            try:
                mobile_list = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "acs-ln-link"]')
                print(mobile_list)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("Sorry, Unable to get the requested element")


    scraper = Amazon_all_mobile_scraper()
    scraper.load_amazon()
    scraper.extract_list_of_mobiles()
```

Please help me to figure out whats wrong in this code.

Comment: What is it you wanna grab from there? Your `xpath` matches nothing.

Comment: That class name is not present on the page as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, SIM and QHarr. Got the mistake.

Comment: @MrSmith42 stop targeting this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only changing from `acs-ln-link` to `acs-ln-links` will not do the trick. Your `xpath` should look more like `'//div[contains(@class,"acs-ln-nav-expanded")]//*[@class="acs-ln-links"]//a'`. This is, however, you can cope with to get the required output:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Amazon_all_mobile_scraper:

    url = "https://www.amazon.in/mobile-phones/b/ref=sd_allcat_sbc_mobcomp_all_mobiles?ie=UTF8&node=1389401031"

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)

    def load_n_get_from_amazon(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        mobile_list = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"acs-ln-nav-expanded")]//*[@class="acs-ln-links"]//a')))
        return mobile_list

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Amazon_all_mobile_scraper()
    for item in scraper.load_n_get_from_amazon():
        print(f'{item.text}\n{item.get_attribute("href")}\n')
```

Comment: You should change `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()` to `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()` for the script to get going.

Comment: Could you please clarify how you formed that XPath or suggest some website from which I can learn to make one that you have written.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your original question @Star Rider. However, you can [check out this link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to learn how xpath can be formed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The class wasn't matching "acs-ln-link" should be "acs-ln-links".